# Lock Methods from Object (Java)

Tags: java, oop

i have the following problem.

i hava a java class

```
 public class A {
    login()
    getRights()
    methodA()
    methodB()
    methodC()
   }
```

now i have the following scenario. I create an instance of class A. and now i want to check with the login function wheter i'm logged in. If not, the object don't have the rights to call method a, b and c. After that i want to check with the getRights() function wheter the object have the rights to call the method b and c. Is there a smart implementation? otherwise i have to inherit from class a and overwrite the blocked functions ?

Comment: `If not the object don't have the rights to call method a, b and c`. Exactly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly but you could either let the methods check for rights right at the start or use some sort of interceptor to check permissions (depends on the frameworks you're using, the general approach would be AOP). That being said having authentication, authorization _and_ business logic in one class is very odd design.

Comment: i dont use any framework

Comment: ok i think. i have to check the permission at the start of any method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could throw an exception if method a, b and c were called but you were not logged in. You just need to use variables to set either that you are logged in or not, and with that throw exceptions or not, and getRights just uses that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can call login() before calling methodA(), or you can write a call to login() inside methodA() so that the code inside methodA() can't be run without running login() first. Then if the object calls methodA() but doesn't return the right value from login() you can throw an exception before going any farther. Then do the same thing with getRights() inside B and C.